# Is there any simple way to extract multiple values from Guava's HashCode?

Tags: guava, hashcode

With Guava, hashing can be as simple as

```
byte[] byteHash = Hashing.md5().hashBytes(aByteArray).asBytes();
```

but seemingly only as all you want is a `byte[]` (possibly converted to a hex string), or a single `int` or `long`. But in one place I need two `long`s and in another one I need five `int` from `sha1`.

I can see some solutions like reading from `new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteHash))`, using a `ByteBuffer`, or converting manually from the `byte[]`. However, all of them are extremely ugly (e.g. swallowing an impossible `IOException`) and long (and also inefficient, but this doesn't bother me here).

So is there any simple way to extract multiple (non-byte) values from Guava's HashCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built in to `HashCode` for this, no.

Doing what you need with `ByteBuffer` seems really easy though, and neither long nor especially inefficient:

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteHash);
long l1 = buf.getLong();
long l2 = buf.getLong();
```

(I suppose an `asReadOnlyByteBuffer()` method could avoid the need for cloning a byte array, but I don't know if that's really necessary.)

Comment: I couldn't recall exactly how `ByteBuffer` gets used for such things and what I found was just terrible, but it's really as simple as it could be. Concerning efficiency: I don't really care, but for a `murmur3_32` 1. you create a `ByteBuffer` to get the bytes via `fromBytesNoCopy` into the `HashCode`. 2. you clone them for me in `asBytes()`, 3. I create a `ByteBuffer` to get back the two longs you started with. One needless allocation and two needless conversions, but not too bad, I guess.

Comment: The only thing that sounds at all like a problem about that is the clone in `asBytes()`, which _could_ be avoided with one new method. But I can't picture an especially good API on `HashCode` for getting multiple numbers out like you want.

Comment: I believe to recall a benchmark where the conversions took quite some time (but that's a long time ago or just my fantasy). I guess, `asReadOnlyByteBuffer` would be good enough. Actually, `HashCode` is just an immutable `byte[]`, i.e., sort of `ByteString`, just pretty limited and with some quirks (`asLong` vs `padToLong`).